# Problems with angular ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have a problem with `ngRepeat` and checkbox:

I use https://github.com/cgarvis/angular-toggle-switch for a styled input checkbox, and use the following template to generate blocks.  If checkbox changed status, then angular must send a request to the server and update this list:

```
<div class="table" ng-repeat="block in items" >
<ul>
<li><toggle-switch model="block.status"><toggle-switch></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But how do I initialize a request if checkbox changed?  In the controller, or watch for change current element? ...please help to understand this moment.

For example:
If I use a simple form `<input type=checkbox ng-model="block.status" ng-change="update()">`
and controller:

```
seomanagerControllers.controller('RelinksCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval',
function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    updateBlocks();
    //$interval(updateBlocks,5000) //use for watch changed

    function updateBlocks() {

        $http.get('/get/blocks')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data
            });
    }

    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log(this.block)
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Use `<input type=checkbox ng-model="block.status" ng-change="update(block)">`, then instead of `this.block`, use `block`

Comment: Yes. its work fine. And its i know. I need a custom checkbox.
ngChange works as a ngClick - if you click on element. But if element is hide - ng-change dont work